# Does `str` implement `Borrow<str>`?

Tags: rust, borrowing

I was looking at the `Borrow<Borrowed>` trait in Rust, and I understand the idea that we want a generic function to allow an argument `K` or its borrowed form `Q` such that `K: Borrow<Q>`. If I look at the `String` implementation, I see that it implements `Borrow<str>`, which explains why passing a `&String` works in the following snippet. What I'm wondering is how can passing a `&str` work: does that imply that `str` implements ... `Borrow<str>`? If not, how can a `str` satisfy the traits of the given `P` generic?

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;
use std::fmt::Display;

fn main() {
    let foo = String::from("I'm a String");
    print(&foo);
    print("I'm a str");
}

fn print<P>(arg: &P) 
where
    P: Borrow<str> + ?Sized + Display
{
    println!("{}", arg)
}
```

Comment: [yes](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=db2b1f87056944d6e032a83ebfece728) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can easily look up in the [doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html#impl-Borrow%3CT%3E-5)

```
impl<T> Borrow<T> for T where T: ?Sized,
```

This means for any type `T`, `Borrow<T>` is implemented for `T`. `where T: ?Sized` means that `T` may be dynamically sized. If trait "bound" (more of a relaxation here) `where T: ?Sized` were not added, then `T` will not include dynamically sized types like `str` or other slice types.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to find the doc on `str` specifically, but it was hidden in the doc of `Borrow` all along :)